# Defining operations on custom classes

Tags: objective-c, class, operators

I want to know how to implement standard operations on any custom class that I create. For example, take a class `A` and three objects of this class a,b and c. If I write down the code `a = b + c`, the compiler won't understand. How can I do to make it understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C does not provide Operator overloading.

So you can not do this in Objective-C.

However you are most aware of this, you have to do like this  `a=[b addWith:c];`

Comment: Yeah that's what I was using but I just wanted a more simple way to do it... Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I knew that why i used **you are most aware** :)

Answer (score 1):

We can't overload operators in this language, if that it what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make sure `a` will always be equal to `b+c`, I don't think there is a way to define it that way.  However, if you override the `init` method for your class, and put `a=b+c;` in there, then never reassign `a` after that, `a` will always equal `b+c`, which I believe is the behavior you are looking for.